# Writing random data to a text file c++

Tags: c++, file, random, io, writefile

I am creating a program that generates a given number of rows of random data, each row has 10 random int values from -50 to 50. The final column is the sum of row values.

I am having trouble writing the random data to a text file. The final column seems to be the only issue when I run it.

I am new to this, so please bear with me.

So far, this is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
void writeData(int, int);

int main() {

    int ROWS;
    const int COLS = 10;

    cout << "Enter number of rows (10-25): ";
    cin >> ROWS;

    writeData(ROWS, COLS);
    return 0;
}//end main


void writeData(int ROWS, const int COLS) {

    //Create an array with column count.
    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    
    //Seed the random number generator.
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    
    //Create and open a file.
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("myfile.txt");

    //Generate a random number (between 10 and 25) of rows of random data.
    //Write random data to file.
    
    outputFile << "[" << ROWS << ", " << COLS+1 << "]\n";
    
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = (rand()%50)+(-50);       //each row has 10 random integer values between -50 and 50
            outputFile << ((int) arr[i][j]) << "\t";
            sum += arr[i][j];   //sum row values
        }

        outputFile << arr[i][COLS] << sum << endl;  //store row sum in last column in the row
        sum = 0;   //reset sum to 0
    }
    
    //Close the file.
    outputFile.close();
    
    //Confirm the data is written to file.
    cout << "The data was saved to the file.\n";
}//end writeData
```

I get this for output:

```
[10, 11]
-5  -7  -28 -48 -12 -2  -29 -28 -40 -18 0-217
-49 -11 -15 -20 -34 -40 -25 -46 -41 -42 1430822061-323
-3  -13 -27 -24 -13 -29 -44 -25 -43 -2  764375682-223
-43 -37 -32 -40 -26 -29 -30 -32 -22 -24 0-315
-31 -12 -2  -12 -38 -15 -27 -36 -24 -21 71091072-218
-11 -49 -48 -47 -10 -44 -32 -22 -31 -7  -343595632-301
-32 -17 -28 -34 -48 -46 -29 -9  -17 -13 0-273
-22 -46 -25 -3  -34 -14 -2  -32 -7  -22 400-207
-5  -13 -13 -14 -17 -47 -28 -19 -5  -36 10-197
-3  -1  -27 -4  -30 -43 -47 -20 -13 -16 -343595600-204
```

I have gotten this far by trial and error. Now, I am stuck. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: `outputFile << arr[i][COLS] << sum << endl;` seems to me theres a few things wrong here, a) arr[i][COLS] is out of bounds because the dimension goes from 0 to COLS-1 (and 0 to ROWS-1 for the other), secondly even if that was valid youd be priting it twice (since the loop does it) and thirdly you have no space between that and sum so you get this weird 0-217 result. I'm pretty sure you just want `outputFile << '\t' << sum << endl;` there

Comment: Not actually a problem, but you could put `int sum = 0;` inside the outer loop that way you wouldnt have to remember to reset it to 0 which makes the code a little bit simpler.

Comment: C++ STL has the `<random>` library, with resources to generate random numbers so you don't have to do it C-style. Check out here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks! I made both changes and it's working correctly now. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things about your program:

- if you want to create numbers in [-50, +50] change `(rand()%50)+(-50)` into `rand()*100-50`
- if you don't reuse `int arr[ROWS][COLS];` for anything: just remove it.
- declare `int sum=0;` in the right place (inside loop)
- don't put `arr[i][COLS]` (also this is an out-of-bounds error since you overshoot the size of `arr`) into your outputFile.

So the correct function should be:

```
void writeData(int ROWS, const int COLS) {

  //Seed the random number generator.
  srand((unsigned)time(0));

  ofstream outputFile;
  outputFile.open("myfile.txt");

  outputFile << "[" << ROWS << ", " << COLS+1 << "]\n";

  for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
      int const value = rand()*100-50;
      outputFile << value << "\t";
      sum += value; 
    }
    outputFile << sum << endl;  //store row sum in last column in the row
  }

  outputFile.close();

}//end writeData
```